# New line for string of text in xml node

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, newline

I would like to read an XML file and add new lines to the output text from a node.  For example:

```
function readXML() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this);
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "test.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();

    function myFunction(xml) {
        var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        var x = xmlDoc2.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].childNodes[0];
        document.getElementById("myTextOutput").innerHTML = x.nodeValue;
    }
};
```

The XML file "test.xml" would have a node:

```
<text>This node would have a string of text.<text>
```

I want to add a new line every time the word "would" and "string" are encountered during the output to a div element called myTextOutput.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer to my own question.

You can add the split() and join() methods attaching them on the x.nodeValue.  The split() you use with the keyword you enter.  Then use the join() to determine if you want a new line or anything else to happen there.  The split() will delete the keyword so I added it in the join() method after my new line so it just adds it back.  This did the trick for me.

```
document.getElementById("myTextOutput").innerHTML = x.nodeValue.split("keywordToFind").join("<br />keywordToFind")
```